# Flutter.h not found

Tags: firebase, flutter

Hello all: I am working on a Flutter App with a team, and the App uses Firebase. When I try to run the App in Xcode, I get an error: Flutter/Flutter.h file not found from FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h (error messages pasted at the bottom of this post). The steps I followed to bring the project over to the Mac from the PC are:

Copied the entire directory for the project
Open the project on the Mac in Android Studio
Run flutter pub get
Open a terminal, cd to the iOS folder
run pod install

but no joy. Can anyone offer any advice? I did have to set the paths to the Dart and Flutter SDKs on the Mac explicitly, and flutter doctor says all is OK, so stuck.
Thanks for any and all input.

/Users/johnstraumann/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-1.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.h:8:9: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/johnstraumann/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-1.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.m:5:9: In file included from /Users/johnstraumann/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-1.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.m:5:

/Users/johnstraumann/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h:8:9: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/johnstraumann/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-1.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.h:12:9: While building module 'firebase_core' imported from /Users/johnstraumann/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-1.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.h:12:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue a week ago.
Updating Firebase Crashlytics to the latest version fixed the issue for me.

After upgrading in pubspec.yaml to the latest version, don't forget to run

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`
- `pod install`
- `pod update`

Comment: Wow, after HOURS AND HOURS, this seems to have fixed it. Had to move a couple things in pubspec and then followed these steps. THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome. It was equally frustrating to me! If my answer helped you please mark it as correct.

Comment: Not to all: I followed this article and changed my pubspec.yaml file, then followed the steps. https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#:~:text=%20Add%20Firebase%20to%20your%20Flutter%20appplat_ios%20plat_android,configuration%20file.%20Click%20Download%20GoogleService-Info.plist%20to...%20More%20

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I update flutter 1.0 to flutter 2.0;
I find just remove next line in Podfile, then `pod install` again, it got fixed;

```
:generate_multiple_pod_projects => true;
```